# How to get contacts of phone using SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, contacts

I am trying to get the contact list in SwiftUI,
in swift i used this Modal to get the contacts from the phone (with the help of Stackoverflow).
but in SwiftUI i am getting error

> Use of undeclared type 'CNContact'

Is ContactsUI CNContact not supportable in swift or i am missing something?

```
import Foundation
import ContactsUI
import SwiftUI
class PhoneContact: NSObject {

    var id: String!
    var name: String?
    var avatarData: Data?
    var phoneNumber: [String] = [String]()
    var email: [String] = [String]()
    var isSelected: Bool = false
    var isInvited = false

    init(contact: CNContact) {
        id = contact.identifier
        name        = contact.givenName + " " + contact.familyName
        avatarData  = contact.thumbnailImageData
        for phone in contact.phoneNumbers {
            phoneNumber.append(phone.value.stringValue)
        }
        for mail in contact.emailAddresses {
            email.append(mail.value as String)
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `import Contacts`

Comment: @Asperi import Contacts gave this warnign: " File 'Contact.swift' is part of module 'Contacts'; ignoring import "

Comment: Check your local declarations, probably you created something that conflicts with Contacts framework